# Computer Refuses to boot up without application of heat

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have an assembled PC with ASUS A-320M motherboard running Ryzen 5 3400G, 16GB RAM and 256GB Samsung 970 Pro M.2 SSD as primary boot drive. I have a clean input power supply system being fed through a APC Easy UPS BVX1200LI-IN 1200VA / 650W UPS.

Its not raining heavily during monsoon in India with humidity > 90% and since onset of monsoons, I am consistently experiencing that my CPU is failing to boot (indicated by no display and non running of CPU and Chassis Fans). The RGB leds on the motherboard glow, however the computer does not boot.

I have tried cleaning the RAM, removed the motherboard and reinstalled it, same for the CPU and CMOS battery, replaced the PSU. Nothing works.

Thereafter, just as a last measure, I used a heat gun to heat up the cabinet internals (with due precaution). After few attempts at switching on the PC, the PC came back to life, booted and ran without a hitch till the next initiated shutdown. Post shut down, the issue persists. It only runs after heating and few attempts at the start button.

What can be the issue?

Comment: what are the max humidity specs of those components?

Comment: I would say the issue is the high humidity, not only for your PC, but for your health as well. You should monitor the humidity in your house and consider purchasing a dehumidifier.

Comment: @golimar  why doesn't it affect other things in the house?